# Outlook email recipient format in web version

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an Excel list with email addresses and code is composing drafts.

When I try to send a mail in web version it states

> error: "This message can't be sent right now. Please try again later."

Mails appear correct in desktop version, but not in web.

```vb
Sub Box()
Dim objOL As Object
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim Name As Namespace
Set Name = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim Msg As MailItem
Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate

Msg.To = Cond.Cells(i, 2).Text
Msg.CC = Cond.Cells(i, 3).Text
Msg.Subject = PP.Range("F1").Text
Msg.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>" & Cond.Cells(i, 4) & Cond.Cells(i, 5) & "</BODY></HTML>"
```

I've tried `To.` property.
I've tried `Recipient.Add` brackets <>.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to specify the file path of the template:

```
Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate
```

The [Application.CreateItemFromTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate) method creates a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) and returns the new item. It requires at least one parameter passed - the path and file name of the Outlook template for the new item.

Second, to set up To and CC properties:

```
Msg.To = Cond.Cells(i, 2).Text
Msg.CC = Cond.Cells(i, 3).Text
```

These properties expect to be set to a semicolon-delimited string list of display names for the `To` or `CC` recipients for the Outlook item. Make sure that you pass a valid string.

A better approach is to use the `Recipients` property of Outlook items. The [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection. Then don't forget to use the `Resolve` or [ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall) methods. They attempt to resolve one or all the `Recipient` objects in the `Recipients` collection against the Address Book, for example:

```
        ' now we add new recipietns to the e-mail
        recipientTo = recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev")
        recipientTo.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo
        recipientCC = recipients.Add("Someone Else")
        recipientCC.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC
        recipientBCC = recipients.Add("eugene.astafiev@somedomain.com")
        recipientBCC.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC
        retValue = recipients.ResolveAll()
```

Read more about that in article that I wrote for the technical blog - [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://reates%20a%20new%20recipient%20in%20the%20Recipients%20collection.).